# Disable what ever causes Vim LaTexSuite from automatically entering braces

Tags: vim, latex, tex, latex-suite

I'm working on a paper using LaTex, and my preferred text editor is Vim. When using the LaTeX plugin from https://github.com/gerw/vim-latex-suite gives me just about everything I need when working with LaTeX.

Sadly there is one thing about the Suite that is driving me nuts. I have a habit when type braces (or quotes) to start by typing the pair (for example `\text{}|`) and then pressing `<esc>i` to place my cursor in between them `\text{|}`. Somewhere in the LaTeX suite there is some script or macro that automatically puts the cursor in between when I type the pair. After my muscle memory that usually leaves me with the cursor infront of the pair `\text|{}`.

How do I disable this 'feature'?

Comment: I just installed this plugin and I don't not see the behavior you are seeing. Are you sure its the plugin that is causing this behavior?

Comment: So if I understand you don't want after typing '\text{}' to place cursor between brackets ('\text{|}'), instead you want '\text{}|', right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly (see my comment) you'll need to comment (or remove) from `main.vim`:

```
call IMAP ('{}','{<++>}<++>',"tex")
```

or change

```
call IMAP ('{}','{}<++>',"tex")
```

or you can call the line above from `~/.vimrc` (or `texrc` or similar) - in this case the latexsuite's definition will override.